# Finding values by Key in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Given a de-serialized JSON object of arbitrary structure and mixed value types...

```
var data = {
  'a':'A1',
  'b':'B1',
  'c': [
    {'a':'A2', 'b':true}, 
    {'a':'A3', 'b': [1, 2, 3]}
  ]};
```

I'd like to return an array of values matching a given key.

```
> my_func(data, 'a')
['A1', 'A2', 'A3']

> my_func(data, 'b')
['B1', true, [1, 2, 3]]
```

The closest I've got is this, which gives the right result, but I think there's a better (faster/neater/more efficient) solution.

```
my_func = function(o,s,a){
    var a = a || [];
    if(o == null){
        return a;
    }
    if(s in o){
        a.push(o[s]);
    }
    for(e in o){
        if(typeof(o[e]) == "object"){
            a.concat(my_func(o[e], s, a))
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a recursive function?

Comment: I built this long time ago (I am not sure how perfect is it): https://github.com/gyandeeps/cclClipper/blob/master/jsonSearch.js

Comment: This is recursive, 'find_in_obj' should be 'my_func'. Can't edit the post yet. - updated

Comment: `a.join(my_func(o[e], s, a))` makes little sense... Did you mean `push`?

Comment: No, my_func returns an array, so it has to be `join` to flatten

Comment: @Craig552uk: That's not what `join` does in JavaScript. `.join` concatenates the array elements to a string.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm being an idiot. That `join` should be `concat`. Typo. Apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your input.
You've inspired me towards the following solution, which I'm much happier with.

```
walk_obj = function(o, fn){
    for(k in o){
        fn(k, o[k]);
        if(typeof(o[k]) == "object"){
            walk_obj(o[k], fn);
        }
    }
}

get_by_key = function(o, key){
    var a = [];
    walk_obj(o, function(k,v){
        if(k==key){
            a.push(v);
        }
    })
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `null` will give a `typeof` of `"object"`, which will break your code.

Comment: Good spot, but it seems fine. `for(k in null){ ... }` does nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
function traverse(obj,func, parent) {
  for (i in obj){
    func.apply(this,[i,obj[i],parent]);      
    if (obj[i] instanceof Object && !(obj[i] instanceof Array)) {
      traverse(obj[i],func, i);
    }
  }
}

function getPropertyRecursive(obj, property){
  var acc = [];
  traverse(obj, function(key, value, parent){
    if(key === property){
      acc.push({parent: parent, value: value});
    }
  });
  return acc;
}
```

call this like this

```
getPropertyRecursive( myobj, 'test' )
```

where `myobj` is the nested object and `test` is the key

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the `replacer` parameter to `JSON.stringify`:

```
function my_func(data, prop) {
  var result = [];
  JSON.stringify(data, function(key, val) {
    if (key === prop) result.push(val);
    return val;
  });
  return result;
}
```